# R caret package (rpart): constructing a classification tree

Tags: r, rpart, r-caret

I am struggling for several days to perform a classification tree using the caret package.
The problem are my factor variables. I generate the tree, but when I try to use the best model to make predictions on the test sample, it fails, because the train function creates dummies for my factor variables and then the predict function cannot find these newly created dummies in the test set. How should I deal with this problem?

My code is as follows:

```
install.packages("caret", dependencies = c("Depends", "Suggests"))      
library(caret)                                      
db=data.frame(read.csv ("db.csv", head=TRUE, sep=";", na.strings ="?"))     
fix(db)
db$defaillance=factor(db$defaillance)
db$def=ifelse(db$defaillance==0,"No","Yes") 
db$def=factor(db$def)
db$defaillance=NULL
db$canal=factor(db$canal)
db$sect_isodev=factor(db$sect_isodev)
db$sect_risq=factor(db$sect_risq)       

#delete zero variance predictors                                
nzv <- nearZeroVar(db[,-78])
db_new <- db[,-nzv]

inTrain <- createDataPartition(y = db_new$def, p = .75, list = FALSE)                               
training <- db_new[inTrain,]
testing <- db_new[-inTrain,]
str(training)
str(testing)
dim(training)
dim(testing)
```

A sample o the str() function for training/testing is found below:

```
 $ FDR        : num  1305 211 162 131 143 ...
 $ FCYC       : num  0.269 0.18 0.154 0.119 0.139 ...
 $ BFDR       : num  803 164 108 72 76 63 100 152 188 80 ...
 $ TRES       : num  502 47 54 59 67 49 53 -7 -103 -109 ...
 $ sect_isodev: Factor w/ 9 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 4 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ sect_risq  : Factor w/ 6 levels "0","1","2","3",..: 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 ...
 $ def        : Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Yes": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
> dim(training)
[1] 14553    42
> dim(testing)
[1] 4850   42
```

Then my code goes like this:

```
fitControl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                           number = 10,
                           repeats = 10,
                   classProbs = TRUE,
                   summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)

#CART1
set.seed(1234)
tree1 = train (def~.,
           training,
           method = "rpart",
           tuneLength=20,
           metric="ROC",
           trControl = fitControl)
```

A sample of

```
summary(tree1$finalModel)
```

is here

```
RNTB          38.397731
sect_isodev1   6.742289
sect_isodev3   4.005016
sect_isodev8   2.520850
sect_risq3     9.909127
sect_risq4     6.737908
sect_risq5     3.085714
SOLV          73.067539
TRES          47.906884
sect_isodev2   0.000000
sect_isodev4   0.000000
sect_isodev5   0.000000
sect_isodev6   0.000000
sect_isodev7   0.000000
sect_isodev9   0.000000
sect_risq0     0.000000
sect_risq1     0.000000
sect_risq2     0.000000
```

And here is the error:

> model.tree1 <- predict(tree1$finalModel,testing)
>       Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'sect_isodev1' not found

I am curious yet about another thing. I have found in Max Kuhn's "Predictive Modelling with R" the following syntax:

```
predict(rpartTune$finalModel, newdata, type = "class")
```

where `rpartTune$finalModel` is a classification tree identical to mine (or mine identical to his).
Now, R doesn't accept type="class". Only type="prob". I am troubled because of that.

Thank you in advance for your responses

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there are two problems:

- R can't find the appropriate `predict` function for `tree1$finalModel`, which should be `predict.rpart` since `tree1$finalModel` is of the class `rpart`. I also get that error and unfortunately don't know the underlying reason. This is also why R does not accept `type = "class"`. `predict.rpart` would accept it.
- Supplying the `train` function with a formula instead of x and y objects leads to the problem that variables like `sect_isodev1` can't be found later on

After reproducing your error with random data (resembling your `str`) using x and y objects and calling `predict.rpart` explicitly from `rpart` worked for me:

```
tree1 = train (y = training$def,
               x = training[, -which(colnames(training) == "def")],
               method = "rpart",
               tuneLength=20,
               metric="ROC",
               trControl = fitControl)
summary(tree1$finalModel)
# This still results in Error: could not find function "predict.rpart":
model.tree1 <- predict.rpart(tree1$finalModel, newdata = testing)
# Explicitly calling predict.rpart from the rpart package works:
rpart:::predict.rpart(object = tree1$finalModel, 
                      newdata = testing, 
                      type = "class")
```

By the way, `predict(tree1, testing)`, which means using `predict.train` with the `train` object, also works and returns predicted classes. **Edit: As Max pointed out, it is usually better to just use this approach instead of making a different `predict` function work.**

Answer (score 13):

**Don't use `predict.rpart`** with the `train$finalModel` unless you have a really good reason. The `rpart` object does;t know about anything that `train` did, including pre-process. It may not give you the correct answer. After all, you might be using `train` in order to avoid the minutia so let `predict.train` do the work.

Max

EDIT -

About the `type = "class"` and `type = "prob"` bit..

`predict.rpart` defaults to producing class probabilities. Although `rpart` is one of the earliest packages, that is atypical as most produce classes by default.

`predict.train` produces the classes by default and you have to use `type = "prob"` to get probabilities.